# FFT transformation a certain multiplication identity

Tags: trigonometry, fast-fourier-transform

Is there always a solution to the following equation:
$$e^{\frac{2i\pi}{2^m}} \cdot e^{\frac{2i \pi w}{2^n}} = \sum_{k=-(m+n)}^{m+n} {b_k \cdot e^{\frac{2 i \pi}{2^k}}}$$

with $m,n,w,b_k$ being integers?

If there is, how do you find $b_k$ in terms of $m,n,w$ and $k$?

This is important for the Fast Fourier Transform, as I have developed a specific algorithm that hinges solely on this property. I would be very glad if there was such an identity for $b_k$, or if anyone could prove there isn't such a thing .

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is an example where you can **not** find $b_k$ so far?

Comment: i haven't tried finding a counter example to this actually...
i know that this should be possible, because you can expand $e^{2ipi/2^{-m}}$ in terms of the $2^{m+n}$ roots of unity which can be easily multiplied with $e^{2ipi/2^{-n}}$ (its basically just a rotation) and then you can re-compress this somehow. But that method takes a long time and haven't been able to figure out a general formula or even if that's always true.

Comment: Again, I ask. What concrete numerical evidence do you have that you can always find $b_k$? What values of $\,m,n,w\,$ have you tried so far?

Comment: so for m=2, n=3 -> $e^{2*pi*i/4}$ * $e^{2*pi*i/8}$ = $(-1) * e^{2*pi*i/8}$, but i guess that's trivial hmm

Comment: so in conclusion i dont know if this is even possible.

Comment: Probably not. All it takes is a single counter example.

Comment: so it's possible if we allow b_k to not be an integer. I dont think it's even possible for m=3, n=4, w=1